# ListView with fixed image

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-resources

I would know if it is possible to create a ListView with a fixed image.
I explain: I have 50 image into the res/drawable folder named for example caffè-icon.png and i would know ho i can do to load this file into a listview of icon.
I know if there is a possibility to do this with for example a `for(i=0;i<images;i++)`or i must do this for each one image in res/drawable.
If is possible i appreciate every example and if is not possible i would know a good method to do this.
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) is a example how to load images from drawable in grid, simply use same adapter for your list.

Comment: tnx Anand. This post is really useful... If my post is useful please rate this post. Thanks...

Comment: @AnandTiwari really tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at this [site](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/creating-image-gallery/) which holds a tutorial for this